# Changing boost::scoped_ptr to std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am using `boost::scoped_ptr` in the code which I would like to replace with `std::unique_ptr`. I would like to know if there are any disadvantages in moving to `std::unique_ptr`. Boost is portable across platforms and compilers. But I am not sure if C++11 supported by all compilers such as MSVC. I know GCC and Clang support C++11 pretty well.

I've already read the SO question “[*`intrusive_ptr` in C++11*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912286/intrusive-ptr-in-c11)” whose short answer is “No”. So If anyone had experience in using both, please share your comments and thoughts

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is specified by the standard so any compliant implementation had better support it.  But I'm not sure what exactly you are asking.  The question you have linked to specifically wanted the semantics by Boost.  Your question seems to be something different but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: vs2010 and forward have an implementation of `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Mgetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332733/mgetz) has generously provided the information that all recent VS implementations supply `unique_ptr`.

I recommend that you replace `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` with `const std::unique_ptr<T>`.  The reason for the `const` is that this most closely models `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` which is not "movable."  However I believe `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` does support swapping. So if you are using that, the compiler will complain everywhere you try to swap a `const std::unique_ptr<T>` and you can then mark those instances as non-`const`.

Comment: Thanks Howard. This answer is helpful

Comment: Is there any perfomance issues or a better performance when using std::unique_ptr